# Cookie not set in request header when request is sent from React

Tags: reactjs, django, web, cookies, fetch

My backend is in Django and Frontend is in React.
I have set up CROS header and added settings as follows.
[Django settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv1sF.png)

For sending request I am using `fetch` and i have set `credentials: 'include'`.

I am using the session based authentication, So when I signin session of a user starts. Then from the parent component (from useEffect) I send a request to backend to fetch Jobs. Things work fine in this case. Below is the header of this particular request. It has `COOKIE`

[Request header 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tSKI.png)

when I send request from child component of react, `COOKIE` is not present in the header. Below is the header of this particular request.

[Request header 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctZjE.png)

I am not able to get why this thing is happening, One more difference in both the request headers is the value of `HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE` in request header.
In first request value of `HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE` is `same-site` whereas in second request `HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE` is `cross-site`. Even though request is sent through `http://localhost:3000` in both cases why value of `HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE` is different.

Answer (score 0):

value of `HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE` was different for these two requests beccause baseurl for first request was set to `http://localhost:8000/`  where as for second request it was
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.

Event though both are local servers on same port, don't know why this thing happens.

I changed both baseurl to `http://localhost:8000/` and things worked. Cookie was set in both the requests.